# Can't do ant run-tests on an Android JUnit project

Tags: android, ant, junit

I am trying to build an AutoTest script that fetches my project from git and then running through the tests in the test project, without having to use any emulator or real device.

I have downloaded the two projects, having them in the same dir and running these commands:

```
$ android update project -p Labyrinth -n Labyrinth
Updated local.properties
Added file Labyrinth/build.xml
Updated file Labyrinth/proguard-project.txt


$ android update test-project -m ../Labyrinth -p LabyrinthTest/
Resolved location of main project to: /home/me/labyrinth-temp/Labyrinth
Updated project.properties
Updated local.properties
Added file LabyrinthTest/build.xml
Updated file LabyrinthTest/proguard-project.txt
Updated ant.properties
Buildfile: /home/me/labyrinth-temp/LabyrinthTest/build.xml
```

Then when i go in to the folder LabyrinthTest and trying to run the tests I get this:

```
$ ant run-tests

BUILD FAILED
Target "run-tests" does not exist in the project "LabyrinthTest". 

Total time: 0 seconds
```

I have googled and tried everything I can find for the past 3-4 hours without any progress. However, running "ant test" with the emulator works! But I want to run it without it.

```
$ ant test
Buildfile: /home/me/labyrinth-temp/LabyrinthTest/build.xml

-test-project-check:

test:
 [echo] Running tests ...
 [exec] 
 [exec] com.app.labyrinth.test.BallTest:...
 [exec] Test results for InstrumentationTestRunner=...
 [exec] Time: 0.034
 [exec] 
 [exec] OK (3 tests)
 [exec] 
 [exec]
```

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second

If the information is needed:

```
Android API version used: 7 (2.1 Eclair)
Android SDK Tools version: 18
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.3 compiled on May 17 2012
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tell what was not working when the **emulator** was not running so I'll guess the problem is (assuming that `adb devices` shows your devices as online) you haven't specified the *serial number* in you ant command line as follows:

```
$ ant -Dadb.device.arg="-s 0123456789" test
```

Comment: No, thats not it either. I want to run it completly without any emulator or device. Just want the JUnit tests to be done on the code. I know this has been possible before, with revision 13 of the Android SDK tools.